# How to join this two tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join, metadata

How to join two queries to get table meta data ?

```
select constraint_type 
from information_schema.table_constraints 
where constraint_schema = 'test' 
and table_name='user';


select table_name,column_name,constraint_name,referenced_table_name,referenced_column_name from 
information_schema.key_column_usage   
where table_schema= 'test' 
and  table_name = 'user';
```

Comment: Read about joins. Then have a close look at your `where` clauses. Do you see something that looks like it's in both queries? If yes, think how you could use this.

Answer (score 0):

Try inner join on schema and name field as below:

```
SELECT constraint_type, table_constraints.table_name,column_name,constraint_name,referenced_table_name,referenced_column_name
FROM information_schema.table_constraints INNER JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage
ON table_constraints.table_name=information_schema.table_name 
AND table_schema = constraint_schema;
```

Comment: Good job, answering such questions leads to worse and worse questions on stackoverflow.